# How to print the first line

Tags: java

My text file includes:

```
Mary,123,s100,59.2
Melinda,345,A100,10.1
Hong,234,S200,118.2
Ahmed,678,S100,58.5
Rohan,432,S200,115.5
Peter,654,S100,59.5
```

and my code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(new FileReader("competitors.txt"));

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String Str=sc.next();
        String [] s=Str.split(",");
        System.out.println(s[0]);
    }   
}
```

I don't know why it will print the first column, I want it prints the first row. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try this `System.out.println(str);`

Comment: Or to put your quiestion in different terms: "I've written code to add 2 numbers together. Why doesn't it multiply them instead?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (new FileReader("competitors.txt"));

    sc.hasNext();
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read the first line then this does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    

    File file = new File("competitors.txt");    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String text = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(text);
    br.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(sc.hasNext()) { // for every line in the file
   String Str=sc.next(); // read that line
   String [] s=Str.split(","); // split it on commas
   System.out.println(s[0]); // print the first element
}
```

Your code loops through every line in the file and splits each line on commas, storing the result in `s`. So for the first line, `s = {"Mary", "123", "s100", "59.2"}`. It then prints the first element of s. For the first line, it prints "Mary". For the second line `s = {"Melinda", "345", ...}`, so it prints "Melinda".

If you want to print just the first line, use:

```
If(sc.hasNext()) {
   String str=sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

As mentioned by @TAsk, you should use `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.next()`, since the latter will read until a space, while the former will read until the end of the line.